# python for loop print in same line in multiple column

Tags: python-3.x, shell

I have a simple loop:

```
for i in range (0,5):
    for a in range(1,10):
        print(string.ascii_uppercase[i] + str(a) + " test")
```

but it outputs:

```
a1 test
a2 test
a3 test
```

what I want is:

```
a1 test   b1 test
a2 test   b2 test
a3 test   b3 test
```

can anyone give me some light on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Just swap the order of your two for loops:

```
for a in range(1,10): 
    for i in range (0,5): 
        print(string.ascii_uppercase[i] + str(a) + " test")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        print(chr(i+98) + str(j) + " test   ", end="")
```

Comment: Add some explanation perhaps?